# How to convert array a to array b below?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have the following two arrays a and b.

```
from numpy import array

a = array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

b = array([[0],
           [1],
           [1],
           [0],
           [0]])
```

How do I convert array a to array b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can handle a vector with the 1-dimension e.g. `[N, ]`.
Here, you want to convert it to a 2D column vector.

### **Use `.reshape()`**

```
from numpy import array

a = array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
print(a.shape)
(5,)

b = a.reshape(-1,1) # this is what you need
print(b.shape)
(5, 1)

print(b)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

**EDIT:**

```
c = a.reshape(1,-1)

c.shape
(1, 5)
```

Comment: That's not "the second dimension empty". `(5,)` is Python syntax for a tuple of length 1, not a tuple with an empty second element. `a` is one-dimensional.

Comment: I agree. Rephrased it.

Comment: Thanks! So you can say array a is a one-dimensional vector and array b is a two-dimensional vector? Also, if I want to create an array with shape (1, 5), how do I do that, say starting with array a?

Comment: see my edit and let me know. `a` is 1-dimensional vector of type `numpy.ndarray`, `b` is a 2d array

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to reshape method is:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
b = a[:,None]
b 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

`None` will add an extra dimension to the array

Comment: Not sure why this one is downvoted either. It's fine.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I guess someone is mad around here lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numpy function called reshape.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,1,0,0])
b = a.reshape(5,1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this one is downvoted. It seems mostly fine, unless it sucked before a grace period edit or something, and it predates the other answers, so it's not just restating what another answer already said.